# Stored Procedure to enter data into table where data and tablename are dynamic

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have Been using Following code ,and I am unable to find where I am going wrong.I have been running the following code its saying error in sql syntax.Please Help me out I am new to mysql and stored procedures.
The Error I am getting is :Error Code 1064,You have sql Syntax error.

```
         CREATE DEFINER=`PotatoHead`@`%` PROCEDURE `InsertIntoTable`(in    
            tablename varchar(45),in ID varchar(45),in Project 
            varchar(45),in Variant varchar(45)
            in ReleaseVersion varchar(45) ,
            in TestBenchID varchar(45) ,
            in TestCaseID int(11) ,
            in TestCaseNamespace varchar(100) ,
            in TestCaseName varchar(45),
            in TestCaseDomain varchar(45) ,
            in TestType varchar(45) ,
            in HardwareVersion varchar(4000) ,
            in SoftwareVersion varchar(4000),
            in Result varchar(45) ,
            in Comment varchar(4000),
            in Duration varchar(45) ,
            in StartTime varchar(45) ,
            in EndTime varchar(45)  )
  BEGIN

  SET @sql = CONCAT('Insert into ', tablename ,' (ID,Project,Variant,
            ReleaseVersion,
            TestBenchID ,
            TestCaseID ,
            TestCaseNamespace ,
            TestCaseName ,
            TestCaseDomain ,
            TestType ,
            HardwareVersion ,
            SoftwareVersion ,
            Result ,
            Comment ,
            Duration ,
            StartTime ,
            EndTime) VALUES (');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(ID,',',Project,',',Variant,',',
    ReleaseVersion,',',
    TestBenchID,',',
    TestCaseID,',',
    TestCaseNamespace ,',',
    TestCaseName ,',',
    TestCaseDomain ,',',
    TestType ,',',
    HardwareVersion ,',',
    SoftwareVersion ,',',
    Result ,',',
    Comment ,',',
    Duration ,',',
    StartTime ,',',
    EndTime,');');
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;



 END
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typo, a missing a comma in your list of input parameters after

```
in Variant varchar(45)
                      ^^^^
```

This is the full error message I got when I ran your code in Workbench

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'in ReleaseVersion varchar(45) ,             in
>   TestBenchID varchar(45) ,        ' at line 6

You edited out the part of the error message which would have told you where to look for the error which will be **before** the quoted code.

Also, if you haven't already done so, you need to reset the DELIMITER before and after a multi-statement procedure definition so that MySQL knows to treat the whole definition as one.

e.g.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`PotatoHead`@`%` PROCEDURE `InsertIntoTable`() 
BEGIN
  Your proc definition
END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

**Update**

That last change should have compiled so now we're onto runtime errors. I confess I didn't look beyond the first error on your original code so didn't notice some of the other problems. e.g.

- multiple assignment to the @sql variable rather than concatenation
- unquoted strings in the values list resulting from concat
- reusing column names for parameters (you'd get away with it here, but can lead to unexpected results)
- however, the big thing I missed was why you'd even want to use dynamic SQL for this problem in the first place, it's just not necessary unless the table name is going to change.

Let's take those in order:

You assign the first part of the INSERT statement to @sql. That's fine. Later you assign the VALUES list to the same variable. At this point you replace the original rather than concatenate the two parts. This is causing the second error you posted. You'd fix it with

```
SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' VALUES(' etc.
```

The CONCAT statement is going to leave the you with a string containing 16 unquoted variable for VARCHAR columns. You'd need to include single quotes around all of those values or the PREPARE statement will fail. You'd fix that one with

```
SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, '\'',
    ID,'\',\'',
    Project,'\',\'',
    Variant,'\',\'',
    ReleaseVersion,'\',\'',
    TestBenchID,'\',\'',
    TestCaseID,',',
    TestCaseNamespace ,'\',\'',
```

etc.

The CONCAT is getting a bit messy now, I think you'll agree.

Next up there's the issue of using the same names for your parameters and the column names in your table. As I mentioned before you'd get away with it in this instance, however MySQL will prioritise the parameter name over the column name when it determines which is being used and this can lead to problems when parameters are used in a SELECT, WHERE clause, etc. It's good practice to distinguish between the two to avoid confusion. So, I'd also rename all of your parameters. e.g.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertIntoTable` (
    in _tablename varchar(45),
    in _ID varchar(45),
    in _Project varchar(45),
    in _Variant varchar(45),
    in _ReleaseVersion varchar(45) ,
```

and then update the VALUES list accordingly. BTW, since all of your input parameters are IN parameters, and that's the default, you can dispense with the 'in' before each one and save yourself some typing.

Finally, your use of dynamic SQL. I suspect this procedure is writing to all the columns of the table and that there is only one table with this exact definition. If the table name isn't going to change, why the need to be able to change it at runtime? If that's not the case, what is your reason for having multiple tables to store the exact same data? If my suspicion is correct, then you can ditch the use of dynamic SQL completely and the procedure will then becomes much simpler

e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertIntoYrTablename` (
    _ID varchar(45),
    _Project varchar(45),
    _Variant varchar(45),
    _ReleaseVersion varchar(45),
    _TestBenchID varchar(45),
    _TestCaseID int(11),
    _TestCaseNamespace varchar(100),
    _TestCaseName varchar(45),
    _TestCaseDomain varchar(45),
    _TestType varchar(45),
    _HardwareVersion varchar(4000),
    _SoftwareVersion varchar(4000),
    _Result varchar(45),
    _Comment varchar(4000),
    _Duration varchar(45),
    _StartTime varchar(45),
    _EndTime varchar(45))
  INSERT into `yrtablename` (
    ID,
    Project,
    Variant,
    ReleaseVersion,
    TestBenchID,
    TestCaseID,
    TestCaseNamespace,
    TestCaseName,
    TestCaseDomain,
    TestType,
    HardwareVersion,
    SoftwareVersion,
    Result,
    Comment,
    Duration,
    StartTime,
    EndTime
  ) VALUES (
    _ID,
    _Project,
    _Variant,
    _ReleaseVersion,
    _TestBenchID,
    _TestCaseID,
    _TestCaseNamespace,
    _TestCaseName,
    _TestCaseDomain,
    _TestType,
    _HardwareVersion,
    _SoftwareVersion,
    _Result,
    _Comment,
    _Duration,
    _StartTime,
    _EndTime);
```

This is much easier to read and maintain and does the job without the troublesome string manipulation. MySQL will take care of quoting the parameters for you and, because it's now a single statement, dispenses with the need for the BEGIN ... END block and resetting the DELIMITER.

Comment: Its Still Not Working,It is saying error Code 1064,Error near Syntax 'ID,Project,Version' At line 1